# Next Record within a group

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have these records grouped by Animal ID since many of the same animals come and go from the facility, so an animal will have multiple records. I want to create a function that gets the length an animal stayed here. However, I want to ignore the animals that have an outcome_type = 'RTO' followed by an intake_type = 'OWNER SUR' within the same. Does anyone know how I can ignore these values. I attached an image for reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL9Dp.png)

Comment: Is it possible for there to be additional datarows between the record with outcome_type = 'RTO' and the record with intake_type = 'OWNER SUR'?  Or will these two records always be one right after the other with no other rows between?

Comment: Most, if not all the time , when an animal leaves as an RTO (outcome_type= 'RTO') and returns as an Owner Surrender (intake_type = 'OWNER SUR') it is right after another. In addition, the Outcome_date will always equal the Intake_date of the following record, i don't know if that helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.